# I am getting an error in my actionlistener on my setText() method because it isn't defined with a string

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtextfield, settext

I am trying to make a simple calculator with three Jtextfields. the first two hold user input and the third displays the result of the calculation. I have converted my users input into strings so it can be displayed, but obviously that is the wrong thing to do. Please help. Here is my code:

```
public class LetsDoMath extends JFrame {

    JLabel instruction1;
    JLabel instruction2;
    JLabel instruction3;
    JTextField input1;
    JTextField input2;
    JTextField result;
    JButton plus;
    JButton minus;
    JButton times;
    JButton divides;


    /**
     * Constructor of LetsDoMath
     *
     */
    public LetsDoMath() {
        setSize(350, 100);
        setTitle("Some Math Functions");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);

        instruction1 = new JLabel("First");
        panel.add(instruction1);

        input1 = new JTextField(4);
        panel.add(input1);

        instruction2 = new JLabel("Second");
        panel.add(instruction2);

        input2 = new JTextField(4);
        panel.add(input2);

        instruction3 = new JLabel("Result");
        panel.add(instruction3);

        result = new JTextField(6);
        panel.add(result);
        result.setEditable(false);

        plus = new JButton("+");
        plus.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(plus);

        minus = new JButton("-");
        minus.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(minus);

        times = new JButton("*");
        times.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(times);

        divides = new JButton("/");
        divides.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(divides);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String msg = event.getActionCommand();

            String x;
            String y;
            double z;


            x = input1.getText();
            System.out.println("Reading " + x + " from the first text field");
            System.out.println("Converted value: "+ Double.parseDouble(x));

            y = input2.getText();
            System.out.println("Reading " + y + " from the first text field");
            System.out.println("Converted value: "+ Double.parseDouble(y));

            if(event.getSource()== plus)
            {
                z = Double.parseDouble(x) + Double.parseDouble(y);
                System.out.println("Result equals: "+z);
                result = Double.toString(z).setText();
                System.out.println("Ready for next input");
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == minus)
            {
                z = Double.parseDouble(x) - Double.parseDouble(y);
                System.out.println("Result equals: "+z);
                result = Double.toString(z).setText();
                System.out.println("Ready for next input");
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == times)
            {
                z = Double.parseDouble(x) * Double.parseDouble(y);
                System.out.println("Result equals: "+z);
                result = Double.toString(z).setText();
                System.out.println("Ready for next input");
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == divides)
            {
                z = Double.parseDouble(x) / Double.parseDouble(y);
                System.out.println("Result equals: "+z);
                result = Double.toString(z).setText();
                System.out.println("Ready for next input");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect that code to do? Yes, `String` doesn't have a `setText()` method. You presumably want to call `setText` on an appropriate text box or label...

Comment: `result = Double.toString(z).setText();` ?? =) String does not have a `setText()`

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not see the result variable declared anywhere :-/

Comment: @LittleChild: Well that's *another* problem, yes. Fundamentally I think the OP needs to take a long hard look at the code and work out what they even *expected* it to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok sorry, it is up top =)

Comment: @LittleChild: Ah, yes. It's hard to see what the assignments to it are really meant to be doing though...

Comment: @JonSkeet Deleted . =)

Comment: thanks for your helpful banter guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change

`result = Double.toString(z).setText();`

to

```
result.setText(Double.toString(z));
```

`setText()` is the a method on your `JTextField` and takes a parameter of what you want to set the `JTextField` to as a string. By passing in your `Double.toString(z)` you will set what text is stored in the `JTextField` to the value of the `Double z`.

If you're looking for some further reading here's the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

`result = Double.toString(z).setText();` is the issue

You are attempting to set text for a `JLabel`. If you need to set the text for JLabel you need to do the following:

```
result.setText(Double.toString(z));
```

and your problem is solved. Add a `main()` and here you go:

[image]